# mvc parameter dictionary contains null entry ..... routing error/problem

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing, global-asax

So I have this controller called Cars, and it has:

```
namespace MySite.Controllers
{
    public class CarsController : ApplicationController
    {

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult New()
        {
            return View();
        }
        [httppost]
        public ActionResult New()
        {
            return View();
        }


        public ActionResult Details(int id)
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Global asax

```
       routes.MapRouteLowerCase(
            "Cars", // Route name
            "Cars/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Cars", action = "Details", id = URLParameter.Optional}
        );

       routes.MapRouteLowerCase(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = URLParameter.Optional} // Parameter defaults
        );
```

So following is the error I'm getting:

> the parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter of non
>   nullable type for method in

NOTE: It's getting me redirected to the **"Details"** View and is asking for an int even thought I wanted to go to the **"New"** view. I'm not really sure what's happening? I basically wanted to have my urls lowercased while removing the "action" on the url on the Promoter routing...Does that make sense? 
Anyhelp is appreciated! Thanks!!!

Comment: Try changing the Details action method to `public ActionResult Details(int? id)` (nullable id)

Comment: i did, same thing, my problem is whenever i hardcode the url /Cars/New, it will point me to /Cars/Details...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> All code below applies to the first route definition.
>   **Second route definition should stay as it is.**

### Your routing is invalid

Take a look at the first route definition:

```
routes.MapRouteLowerCase(
    "Cars", // Route name
    "Cars/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Cars", action = "Details", id = URLParameter.Optional}
);
```

And when you access `Cars/New` this first route gets hit because all parameters are easily applied as:

- controller = `"Cars"`
- action = `"Details"`
- id = `"New"`

If you'd like the first route definition to only cover certain IDs you should put a constraint onto it or change your routing. Constraint for numeric IDs should look like this:

```
routes.MapRouteLowerCase(
    "Cars", // Route name
    "Cars/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Cars", action = "Details" },
    new { id = @"\d+" }
);
```

When you'd access `Cars/New` first route wouldn't be hit because `New` doesn't satisfy ID constraint so route processing would continue with the next route (which would resolve it just fine - as it should).

Mind the fact, that `id` isn't optional anymore. In case of putting a constraint onto it it can't be. If you have a `Details` controller action it should most probably display some certain details. So it actually needs some ID.

Comment: so what if i wanted to go to a specific cars details let's say Cars/Details/2 ... but i want to display it as Cars/2 ... how do i deal with that? without compromising the Route for Cars/New (which btw will be the action for creating new Car profiles)..

Comment: @gdubs: When you'd create links using `Html.ActionLink` they'll always come out as **Cars/2** and not **Cars/Details/2** even though it would still work just fine. But it depends whether you want this multifaceted routing. Otherwise put a constraint on the second route to not allow *Details* action name. So only the first URL will actually route to details. And be aware that **Cars/New** will still work just fine, because `id` in second route is still optional.

Comment: @gdubs: mind the note at the top of my answer regarding the first route definition.

Comment: is it recommended though? having this kind of routing? Sorry, im new with mvc so i'm experimenting on stuff, im just trying to imitate some websites i saw that can recognize if a user types the url by themselves, of course not on every route, but on some. eg. Cars/(name of specific car) will redirect them to the profile/details of that car

Comment: btw Robert, the 2nd route (new { id = "\d+"}) is giving me an "unrecognized escape sequence error. is it supposed to be inside the first route?

Comment: I think it is missing @ before the expression `id = @"\d+"`

Comment: @gdubs: **All code in my answer applies to first route only**. Never mind the second one. That one's fine. And about the recommendation: there's no specific recommendation. Whatever you need you have to do it. So if your requirements have the need to match car details as you described, then constraining `id` with numbers won't do the trick. But you will have to have complex routing with constraint. Unless you don't use `CarsController` class, because the first route's URL definition with static string matches your controller name.

Answer (score 0):

If your route is setted like this

```
routes.MapRouteLowerCase(
    "Cars", // Route name
    "Cars/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Cars", action = "Details", id = URLParameter.Optional}
);
```

that means that any URL that starts with "/Cars/..." will redirect you to Details action, that includes "/Cars/New" and it will try to map the "New" string to the id parameter that is why you get the error.

Comment: yeah just found out about that. but like what i told Robert, how do I handle removing the "Details" action from the URL without comprimising the "New" action. eg. I the user wants to view details of carid 2.. instead of showing /Cars/Details/2, i want to show /Cars/2 ...